# How to execute PowerShell script as administrator from Visual Studio C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script it works just fine when I run it in PowerShell ISE as an admin.

But when I run it from my C# code it doesn't work:

```
InitialSessionState runspaceConfiguration = InitialSessionState.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);

runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
string rawScript = File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);

using (PowerShell posh = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand(@scriptPath))
{
    string script = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; Get-ExecutionPolicy"; // the second command to know the ExecutionPolicy level
    posh.AddScript(script);

    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in parameters)
    {
        posh.AddArgument($"{(string)de.Key}, {de.Value}");
    }

    posh.Invoke();

    Collection<PSObject> psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
}
```

I tried setting `ExecutionPolicy` to unrestricted, and running Visual Studio as an admin but it didn't work

Comment: Launch VS as administrator, child processes will inherit the security token

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I already did

Comment: Then elaborate on "it doen't work" - does the computer catch on fire? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it tells me that running scripts is disabled in the system

Comment: That has nothing to do with running as admin or not, you need to update the execution policy on the target system (preferably via a GPO or MDM policy if it's an enterprise/managed device)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes i changed the execution policy but still  , that's the result when i executed Get-ExecutionPolicy -list      Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    Unrestricted
  CurrentUser    Unrestricted
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Turn on Script Execution Group Policy setting to manage the execution policy of computers in your enterprise. The Group Policy setting overrides the execution policies set in PowerShell in all scopes.

The Turn on Script Execution policy settings are as follows:

If you disable Turn on Script Execution, scripts do not run. This is equivalent to the Restricted execution policy.

If you enable Turn on Script Execution, you can select an execution policy. The Group Policy settings are equivalent to the following execution policy settings:

[image]
The PowerShellExecutionPolicy.adm and PowerShellExecutionPolicy.admx files add the Turn on Script Execution policy to the Computer Configuration and User Configuration nodes in Group Policy Editor in the following paths.

For Windows XP and Windows Server 2003:

Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell

For Windows Vista and later versions of Windows:

Administrative Templates\Classic Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell

Policies set in the Computer Configuration node take precedence over policies set in the User Configuration node.